# Update tables in database from tables in a different form

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have one working import xml to my mysql, which import to tables.
Now I want to update with these imported tables my new tables. But I don't know how.

The importer import from 3 different xml.
products, price, stock

It's import to `products`, `product_descriptions`, images, etc

Example:

```
Products
ID | Name      | stock | date
1  | product 1 | 9999  | 2013.07.13
2  | product 2 | ....

Product_description
ID | description           | price | date       | sale price
1  | product 1...          | 1$    | 2013.07.17 | 0$
2  | Product 2 is blabla.. | 999 $ | 2013...    | 10$
```

I want to update with these items my another tables:

```
posts
Post ID | post title    | description                     | product ID
100     | products-name | product_description-description | product-ID <- with these item from another tables.
```

and,

```
postmeta
post id | meta       | value
100     | price      | products_description - price
100     | sale price | product_description - sale price
100     | title      | products-name
100     | image      | imagepath
```

I don't know how can I do this. 
Anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use INSERT INTO ... SELECT construction.

There is a nice manual from MySQL: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-select.html

For instance,

```
INSERT INTO posts (post_title, description)
   SELECT 
      Products.Name, Products.stock
   FROM Products
```

This will insert to the posts table all names & stock levels of your products in a title and description columns

P.S. I do not see any connection between Products and Product Description. Are there any foreign keys?

Comment: Oh, ID is the product ID, sry. :)

Comment: And, i can make this update automaticaly in every day after the import?